# php extract body tag content

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I'm trying what should be very easy, but I can't get it to work. Which makes me wonder if I'm using the right workflow.

I have a simple html page which I load in my desktop application as a help file. This page has no menu just the content.
On my website I want to have a more sophisticated help system. So I want to use a php file which will show a menu, breadcrums and a header and footer.
To not duplicate my help content I want to load the original HTML help file and add its body content to my enhanced help page.

I'm using this code to extract the title:

```
function getURLContent($filename){
    $url = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
    @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
    return $doc;
}

function getSingleElementValue($element){
  if (!is_null($element)) {
    $node = $element->childNodes->item(0);
    return $node->nodeValue;
  }
} 

$doc = getURLContent("test.html");
$title = getSingleElementValue($doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0));
echo $title;
```

The title is correctly extracted.

Now I try to extract the body:

```
function getBodyContent($element){
  $mock = new DOMDocument;
  foreach ($element->childNodes as $child){
      $mock->appendChild($mock->importNode($child, true));
  }        
  return $mock->saveHTML();
}

$body = getBodyContent($doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));
echo $body;
```

The getBodyContent() function is one of the several options I tried.
All of them return the whole HTML tag, including the HEAD tag.

My question is: Is this a correct workflow or should I use something else?

Thanks.

**Update:** My final goal is to have a website with multiple pages that has the help files accessible via a menu. These pages will be generated using something like generate.php?page=test.html. I'm not yet at this part. The goal is also to not duplicate the content of test.html because this file will be used in my desktop application (using a web control). In my desktop application I don't need the menu and such.

**Update #2:** I had to add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` to the html-file I want to read and now I do get the body content. Unfortunaly all tags are strips. I'll need to fixed that as well.

Comment: what is the final goal? To form different tags of every page dynamically?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `saveHTML()` will return an actual document. You don't want this. Instead, you want just what you put in.

Thankfully, you can do this much more easily.

```
function getBodyContent(DOMNode $element) {
    $doc = $element->ownerDocument;
    $wrapper = $doc->createElement('div');
    foreach( $element->childNodes as $child) {
        $wrapper->appendChild($child);
    }
    $element->appendChild($wrapper);
    $html = $doc->saveHTML($wrapper);
    return substr($html, strlen("<div>"), -strlen("</div>"));
}
```

This wraps the contents into a single element of known tag representation (the body may have attributes that make it unknown), gets the rendered HTML *from that element*, and strips off the known tag of the wrapper.

I'd also like to suggest an improvement to `getSingleElementValue`:

```
function getSingleElementValue(DOMNode $element) {
    return trim($element->textContent);
}
```

Note also the use of type hints to ensure that your functions are indeed getting the kind of thing that is expected - this is useful as it means we no longer need to check "does `$element->ownerDocument` exist? does `$element->ownerDocument->saveHTML()` do what we think it does?" and other such questions. It ensures we have a `DOMNode`, so we *know* it has those things.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've got it working now.