# Getting Google Translate's html codes in php

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents, google-translate

after reading these in below, I still can't see the solution :
[Extract data from website via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019892/extract-data-from-website-via-php)
[php extract body tag content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436375/php-extract-body-tag-content)

after i using

`file_get_contents("https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=fa&text=Help%20Me")`

It seems it doesn't contain the words that I typed in box of translator(the words:Help Me)

How can i get all the data from start to end that contains the word that user(myself) typed?

Comment: You are using website translator as an API which you shouldn’t (because there are likely Javascripts in that page that make requests to server for translation). You need an [SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-translate) to perform these kinds of tasks instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Translate uses Javascript to read & display the translated text. It is not available in the source code. You can verify this by viewing the source of the URL you provided yourself (e.g. by copying `view-source:https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=fa&text=Help%20Me` into your address bar). It's also against their terms of service.

To access Google Translate programmatically you need to use the [Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs). This API provides $10/month of free usage, which is enough for most hobbyist projects.

Here is more information on [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing) and [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas), and even [a handy guide to using PHP with it](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/php).

Comment: thank you very much, but why we can see the word in html(chrome or firefox or others) but we cant get that from php and text? i mean it should be something like a protocol or something that can get the data and send it to website and that we get the data from html...

Comment: The protocol you just described exists. It's the API I linked!